# img src path in Ionic v1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

im using ionic v1
and this is my folder structure.

```
www\tempaltes\acct\
```

under my **acct** folder, I have *acct-home.html* and *patient_default.png*

im trying to display my *patient_default.png* in *acct-home* using this code.

```
<img src="patient_default.png" alt="Test" width="100px" height="100px">
```

Note that *acct-home.html* and *patient_default.png* are on the same folder.
But it does not display correctly.
Am i doing this wrong? Your help will really appreciated.

**Updated Question:**

this is my folder structure

```
root
   --API
      --patient_default.png
   --Www
      --templates
         --acct
           --acct-home.html
```

i tried using

```
<img src="../../API/patient_default.png" alt="Test" width="100px" height="100px">
```

it shows nothing.

[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: I think the root folder (where is launched the app) is not same as acct-home.html's folder. Try to write path from index.html

Comment: @HugoTor, that worked sir!. Thank you very much. I have an additional question. How do i reference an image outside www folder?

Comment: nice, I've posted the answer then. I advice you to stay in the www folder. But if you need to go out, just use '../path'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `src="patient_default.png"` kind you can access only when your in the index or app initiation view....But in your case you need to access from sub folders.For that you need to show the correct path to src attribute like `src="../your image containingfolder /logo.png"`.This is just like showing the direction in reverse.

**And for your update** 
you need to increase the `../` up to that folder like assume if `"../your image containingfolder /logo.png"` indicates from your www folder you need to add one more like `"../../your image containingfolder /logo.png"`to accees them but make sure they are available at that location

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! :D
I have another question
I have this folder structure.
root
 --API
 --www
      --templates
          --acct
             -- acct-home.html

how do I access the image inside my API folder?

Comment: is that above mentioned is the  exact path like root folder having API folder and that API folder contains WWW .......like this or any of these are sub folders of root??

Comment: I updated my question, thank you very much for your time and help :D

Comment: so you want to access image in www folder which is in another folder called API right

Comment: i want to access an image in my API folder.

Comment: Why not use your API in order to return image link ?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use your templates folder as absolute path head.

Use *index.html* instead, it will work !

index.html will use .html templates, but with Ionic, the reference is always index.html.

Comment: say Foo is my project folder.
so Foo contains www folder and patient_default.png
when I try to use "../patient_default.png" it display nothin

Comment: As said Sa E Chowdary, you need to add one more ../

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in `www\img`and then save `patient_default.png` in this folder after that

Try this

```
<img src="www/img/patient_default.png" alt="Test" width="100px" height="100px">
```